# Creating polygon regions with latitude and longitude values in qgis?

Tags: polygon, coordinates, qgis-2

I've a set of places with their latitudes and longitudes, I've plotted them on QGIS but what I want is to create polygon from these points so that each point refers to a particular region around it. It's my first attempt at QGIS so I am completely new to it, if anyone could help?

Some of the points are :-

```
Dudhli  29.9713363  77.6049218
Raiwala 30.0254474  78.219132
Ajabpur 30.0431765  78.8255226
Fatehpur    30.0444012  77.7609435
Johdi   30.064216   77.5939097
Barontha    30.066753   79.0192997
```

I have around 106 such points.

Comment: How do you propose you take a single point and produce a region from it? Are these "official" regions? If so, then you may be better off downloading the polygons that have already being defined than trying to infer your own from a single point.

Comment: @RichardLaw Yes these are official regions, as in the places where some hospitals are located. How do I download these polygons?

Comment: So, actually you do not want to create polygons from your points, but you want an additional layer which has your regions. Obtaining such can be difficult as there is not always free map data available. You could have a look at the [NaturalEarthData](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) site, maybe they have what you are looking for. Or OpenStreetMap, which you can integrate directly into QGIS in different ways with the help of some plugins. But this is probably out of the scope of your question.

Comment: I did try OpenStreetMap but results are sadly not loading.

Comment: By "region" do you mean an actual, official administrative district with an agreed boundary, or do you mean something like "the space 500m around a point"?

Comment: @RichardLaw I'll like to start with a space of 500m radius around it the point

Comment: OK so the conventional term you want is a "buffer", not a region, which typically means something else. Look for the buffer tool under the vector menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the buffer tool it will create a circle of a specified distance around each point.